# Zoom automático

Tags: java, android

Não sei essa função é nativa da API do Google Maps mas não estou conseguindo inciar o mapa com zoom na minha localização, segue meu código.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtendo referência a SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Criando GoogleMap de SupportMapFragment
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Ativando o botão MyLocation para o mapa do Google

        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Definir ouvinte OnClickEvent para o GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
                addMarker(latlng);
                sendToServer(latlng);
            }
        });



        //  Locais de partida recuperar tarefa
        new RetrieveTask().execute();
    }


    //Adicionando marcador no GoogleMaps
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    // Invocando discussão de fundo para armazenar o local tocado em Remover servidor MySQL
    private void sendToServer(LatLng latlng) {
        new SaveTask().execute(latlng);
    }
    // Segmento de segundo plano para salvar o local em remover servidor MySQL
    private class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            String lat = Double.toString(params[0].latitude);
            String lng = Double.toString(params[0].longitude);
            String strUrl = "http://t4web.hospedagemdesites.ws/alarme/save.php";
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        connection.getOutputStream());

                outputStreamWriter.write("lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();

                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";

                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);

                }

                // Atualizar no momento que salvar uma nova posição \o/

                new RetrieveTask().execute();
                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

                //final do while é aqui

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

    }



    // Tarefa de fundo para recuperar locais de servidor mysql remoto
    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://t4web.hospedagemdesites.ws/alarme/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                String line = "";
                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }



    // Discussão de fundo para analisar os dados JSON recuperados do servidor MySQL
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>>{
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
                addMarker(latlng);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflar o menu ; este adiciona itens à barra de ação se ela estiver presente
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: O mapa nem começa mostrando sua localização ou já mostra e você quer apenas que ele comece com zoom nessa localização?

Comment: Sim, ele deve aplicar o zoom na minha localização assim que abrir o map.

Comment: No seu código não mostra como você obtem as coordenadas do usuário. Usando apenas `setMyLocationEnabled` você obtem um marcardo no mapa mas ela não te dá essa informação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer simplesmente setar um zoom (seu mapa já estando nas coordenadas corretas), você pode fazer:

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13); // valor do zoom
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
```

Porém, o método `moveCamera(update)` faz uma mudança brusca na camera, se você quer que vá aumentando de forma animada, você pode usar o:

```
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);
```

***Outros:***

Outros métodos interessantes para lidar com o zoom, são:

```
CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn();
```

*-> Esse método aumenta o zoom em 1*.

```
CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut();
```

*-> Esse método diminui o zoom em 1.*

```
CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10);
```

*-> Esse método aumenta ou diminui o zoom do mapa, dependendo do valor informado*

***EDIT: obtendo a localização***

Para se obter a última localização de forma eficiente você deve usar a `FusedLocationApi`, porém, para usá-la é preciso criar e se conectar a um `GoogleApiClient`. Então vamos lá:

Criando um `GoogleApiClient`:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
...
// Isso é feito no onCreate() da activity ou fragment
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API) // Informamos a API de localização
                .build();
```

Com o objeto criado, precisamos realizar a conexão e depois desconexão, o que, segundo a documentação do google deve ser feito no onStart() e no onStop(), respectivamente:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Você também precisa fazer com que sua activity ou fragment implementem  `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` e `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, para você saber quando a conexão foi bem sucedida ou interrompida e para saber se houve falha, respectivamente:

```
implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener ... {
```

Feito isso, você terá que implementar os seguintes três métodos:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "conectado ao google play services");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "conexão interrompida");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "erro ao conectar: " + connectionResult);
}
```

Se tudo ocorrer como o esperado, o método `onConnected(Bundle bundle)` será chamado e nele que você deve obter a localização, dessa forma:

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
Log.d("DEBUG", "conectado ao google play services");
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
        setMyLocation(location);
    }

    private void setMyLocation(Location location) {
        if (mGoogleMap != null && location != null) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13); // seta o local e já o zoom
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);
        }
    }
```

Lembrando que o método: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)` vai retornar a última localização conhecida.

Comment: `Os valores válidos para zoom são de 2 a 22` não é verdade. O zoom inicia em zero e valor máximo depende de qual posição do globo a camera aponta, conforme a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom).

Comment: @Androiderson, obrigado. Vou atualziar a resposta!

Comment: Ele está aplicando o zoom em um local aleatório do mapa e não da minha localização, pode ser pela minhas coordenadas ?

Comment: Isso é porque você não setou suas coordenadas no mapa.  Pela sua resposta nos comentários achei que você já tinha setado e o problema era apenas o zoom. Logo eu atualizo a resposta com essa solução.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Luiz.

Comment: Editei a resposta, dê uma olhada!